# mysql prevent deleting records that is in used

Tags: mysql

i got 2 tables. product and order_items which contain all the products that were bought.

so how do i create a relationship in mysql whereby if a product exists in order_items, restrict users from deleting it from product table??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with Foreign keys with the InnoDB Engine.

```
ALTER TABLE order_items ADD FOREIGN KEY (`p_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`p_id`);
```

The ID on products must be a key (it probably already is the primary key).

If you are not using InnoDB, you cannot enforce this with MySQL, but it must be enforced with your application (check whether a record exists in orders first for example).

So with your tables, you run:

```
ALTER TABLE `order_item` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`bookid`) REFERENCES `book` (`id`);
```

Comment: Thanks for writing out the code. ON DELETE RESTRICT is default.

Comment: hi i got an error: Category    Timestamp    Duration    Message    Line    Position
Error    10/10/2010 2:21:04 PM    0:00:00.000    MySQL Database Error: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`databasename`.`#sql-248_72`, CONSTRAINT `#sql-248_72_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`p_id`) REFERENCES `products` (`p_id`))    1    0

Comment: I don't know the table structure that you have.  I was just guessing with p_id.  Use the real key/column names, obviously, or post your table structure so I can help you out.

Comment: hi pls see above for my table structure

Comment: I don't see?  I am talking about showing me the contents of SHOW CREATE TABLE for both the products and order items tables.

Comment: i submitted an ans with my my table structure.. saw that??

Comment: Oh I see; I was expecting an edit to the main post.  Edited my answer to be specific for yours.

Comment: Are there any rows on order_item with bookid that do not have a matching id on book?

Comment: oh yes. thats the problem.. i deleted those records and now it works. tks tandu!!

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for a foreign key. Specifically look at the "Restrict" option.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html

Answer (score 0):

my table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `book` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `userid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `description` text NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `edition` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `isbn` varchar(13) NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(11) NOT NULL,
  `datesubmitted` datetime NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=30 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `order_item` (
  `orderid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bookid` int(11) NOT NULL,
  KEY `Foreign` (`bookid`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```